# In limited memory, use Apache POI to write data in specified rows and columns to an excel file that already has a large amount of data

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, out-of-memory, excel-writer-xlsx

I want to append data on an existing excel file, my code is as follows:

```java
XSSFWorkbook book = new XSSFWorkbook("/my.xlsx");
Sheet sheet = book.getSheetAt(1);
//do something
```

But this file already has a lot of data, so I get out of memory error.

I know it is possible to use `SXSSFWorkbook`, but this doesn't work for me, because it still loads the existing data into memory:

```java
new SXSSFWorkbook(new XSSFWorkbook("/my.xlsx"));
```

How can I solve this problem with limited memory? thanks in advance.

As mentioned above, I hope that I can write data in specified rows and columns to an excel file that already has a large amount of data in limited memory.

Comment: https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api

Comment: you could try https://github.com/pjfanning/excel-streaming-reader/wiki/Streaming-copy-with-SXSSF